# internal messaging system laravel database design

Tags: php, sql, database, laravel, eloquent

I am building an internal messaging system for a forum that I have built with Laravel 5.3. Basically, I want to have messaging functionality, similar to Linkedin- `User` can send an email to another `User` and vice versa. There is going to be a single thread for a given conversation, which will take place between two users. I have been looking through some questions on StackOverflow, but haven't quite found what I am after- in terms of database design.

Here is what I was thinking:

`messages`:

- id PK
- sender_id FK to `users`.`user_id`
- content

`message_recipients`:

- id PK
- message_id FK to `messages`.`id`
- recipient_id FK to `users`.`id`

However, I am not 100% sure on the types of relationships there should be between the `users`, `messages` and `message_recipients`. Users would have many messages. Messages would belong to a User. But, how would I factor in the `message_recipients` table?

Feel free to suggest a different design :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create just one table with `id`, `sender_id`, `recipient_id`, `message`.

`sender_id` and `recipient_id` are foreign keys pointed to `users` table.

It's [many to many relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) and you can treat this table as pivot, so you can define `belongsToMany` relations. Also you can create model for this table if you will work with it a lot.

Comment: Thank you. I will try this out :)

Comment: @AshMenhennett you've asked about using relations, it should be two `belongsTo()` relations defined in `User` model to itself, but with different foreign keys. If it sounds alien to you, create `Message` model and use two `hasMany()` relations between `User` and `Message`, you'll get simplier way to work with messages and more readable code. Both ways are good in different situations.

Comment: thank you for the input. I will take a look at this.

Comment: if I use 2 ```hasMany()```, one in ```User and one in ```Model```, does it require a ```belongsTo()``` anywhere?

Comment: No, no. You should use two `hasMany()` in `User` model. One to get messages for recipient and one to get messages for sender. In `Message` model you should also create two `belongsTo()` relations with using different foreign keys to get user data (first name, for example) by user ID. For example, relations defined in `Message` will look like these `belongsTo('App\User', 'sender_id', 'id');` and `belongsTo('App\User', 'recipient_id', 'id');` Maybe more [examples](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse) will be also helpful.

Comment: Works Perfectly! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Try this kind of structure:

```
messages:

id          - int, autoincrement id
parent_id   - int. To maintain message threads
sender_id   - int. Senders Id
recipient_id- int. Recievers Id
content     - text, Message content
status      - enum('0', '1') for Read, Unread, Deleted etc
```

or break it into 2 or 3 table by maintaining the foreign key relationship.

Comment: Cheers! Thank you for the input.

Comment: How about if receiver isn't just user ? Maybe receiver might be team, guest..

Comment: @lovecoding-laravel in that case create another table for receivers and maintain `one-to-many` relationship